# Deadlock when trying to display text while data read in DataReceived event handler of serialport

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, serial-port

- I'm implementing a serial protocol between a PC and an embedded device.
- I'm sending a content of a file to the device from the PC in chunks.
- Before I'm starting to send the file I'm sending its name and size, then wait for an ACK from the device and then start a loop to send the chunks and wait for ack on each chunk.
- I'm using events to sync the received ACKs in the DataReceived thread with the main thread that sending the chunks.

**The problem:** 
All the aboved worked fine until I add this line:

```
textBoxLog.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => textBoxLog.AppendText(str)));
```

so I can update the user about the progress of the sending, when this line is in the code the events are not received in the main thread and the program is in a deadlock.

Any idea why?

This is a short summarize of the code:

```
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        AutoResetEvent waitHandle_1 = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        AutoResetEvent waitHandle_2 = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            try
            {
                myPort = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM37");
                myPort.BaudRate = 460800;
                myPort.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;
                myPort.DataBits = 8;
                myPort.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One;
                myPort.Handshake = System.IO.Ports.Handshake.None;
                myPort.ReadTimeout = 5000;
                myPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(SerialPortDataReceived);

                if (myPort.IsOpen == false) //if not open, open the port
                    myPort.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        // Serial port received event handler
        private void SerialPortDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            while (myPort.BytesToRead > 0)
            {
                var count = myPort.BytesToRead;
                var bytes = new byte[count];
                myPort.Read(bytes, 0, count);
                AddResponseBytes(bytes);
            }
        }

        List<byte> Data = new List<byte>();
        private void AddResponseBytes(byte[] bytes)
        {
            // Analyzing message byte, wait for full message
            ProcessResponse(responseData, msgType);
        }

        private void ProcessResponse(List<byte> bytes, mixCommandType responseType)
        {
            String str;

            switch (responseType)
            {
                case CommandType.PC_TO_DEVICE_RESPONSE:
                    str = "Test text";
                    waitHandle_1.Set();
                    textBoxLog.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => textBoxLog.AppendText(str)));
                    break;
                case CommandType.CHUNK_ACK:
                    waitHandle_2.Set();
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void buttonSendFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Open file and send message to device with file size and wait for ACK

            waitHandle_1.WaitOne();

            Console.WriteLine("Got response - Continue to send");

            uint i = 0;
            while (i < bytes.Length)
                {
                    //Send chunk of the file to the device and whait for chunk ack
                    waitHandle_2.WaitOne();
                }
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `Invoke` dispatches whatever you pass it to UI (main) thread (that you probably know already), but your UI thread is already busy, it is blocked in `buttonSendFile_Click` here:

```
waitHandle_1.WaitOne();
```

or here

```
waitHandle_2.WaitOne();
```

`Invoke` is also blocking call - it will not return until dispatch is completed - so you have classical deadlock.

In general it's bad to block UI thread, especially by waiting on wait handles. To resolve your issue - use background thread to perform what you now do in `buttonSendFile_Click` handler.

Comment: Also you can add `async` to the event handler and do asynchronios all the way